# Firebase Cloud function triggers twice onUpdate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have below rules set for my `firebase collection - payments`

```
"payments": {
    "$paymentId": {
        "totalAmount": {
        },
        "balanceAmount": {
            ".validate": "newData.val()<=data.child('totalAmount').val()"
        },
        "paymentDetails": {
            "$detailId": {
                "amount": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isString()"
                },
            }
        },
    }
}
```

and below cloud function written to handle certain updates on that collection:

```
exports.calculateBalance = functions.database
.ref('payments/{pushId}')
.onUpdate(event => {
    const paymentRef = event.data.adminRef;
    const payment = event.data.val();
    return paymentRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        var paidAmount = 0;
        snapshot.child("paymentDetails").forEach(function(child) {
            paidAmount += parseFloat(child.child("amount").val());
        });
        return paidAmount;
    }).then(snap => {
        payment.balanceAmount = parseFloat(payment.totalAmount) - snap;
        return paymentRef.set(payment);
    })
});
```

Its simple, whenever I add a payment details, I want to update the `balanceAmount`. The problem here is, whenever an update occurs at that collection, the function triggers **twice**. First time its obvious from application and 2nd time its because of `paymentRef.set(payment);` line.

Is there any possible way I can avoid this 2nd trigger on cloud function? I cannot use any flag on `collection` level since the update on payment details happens multiple times. Can someone guide me in the right direction on this?

**EDIT**

Note - I've an edit option for payment details entered.

Comment: you can can `off` to remove the listener on that node and then call `on` to set the listener again (i'm not a good web developer but i use this approach at android)

Comment: Can you update a payment detail or just create it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want update the **balance amount** only when you add a payment details you can use the **onCreate** trigger directly on the payment details.

Try something like that (You have to update the code for your case) :

```
exports.calculateBalance = functions.database.ref('payments/{pushId}/paymentDetails/{detailId}').onCreate(event => {
    var paymentRef = event.data.adminRef.parent.parent;
    var paymentDetailSnapshot = event.data;
    var paymentDetailAmountSnapshot = paymentDetailSnapshot.child('amount');

    return paymentRef.child('balanceAmount').transaction(current => {
        return current - paymentDetailAmountSnapshot.val(); // Balance can be negative
    });
});
```

(Use the transaction to manage concurrent modifications)

[Transactions documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

**NOTE**

Please, use directly a **Number** for your **amount data** not a **String**.

**UPDATE**

Add this function to manage the update :

```
exports.recalculateBalance = functions.database.ref('payments/{pushId}/paymentDetails/{detailId}').onUpdate(event => {
    var paymentRef = event.data.adminRef.parent.parent;

    var paymentDetailSnapshot = event.data;
    var previousPaymentDetailSnapshot = event.data.previous;

    var paymentDetailAmountSnapshot = paymentDetailSnapshot.child('amount');
    var previousPaymentDetailAmountSnapshot = previousPaymentDetailSnapshot.child('amount');

    return paymentRef.child('balanceAmount').transaction(current => {
        return current + previousPaymentDetailAmountSnapshot.val() - paymentDetailAmountSnapshot.val(); // Balance can be negative
    });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate this and yea suits perfectly, but there is an edit option too in the application, so I doubt this wouldnt help much.. :(

Comment: Give me a moment.. Am checking it.. :)

Comment: You mentioned _// Balance can be negative_ Anyways to overcome this?

Comment: It's just an example, you can return what you want

Comment: Ok.. am bit confused here.. Could you please let me know how this avoids multiple updates?

Comment: The event is added on the path 'payments/{pushId}/paymentDetails/{detailId}' but when you update the balance amount the path is 'payments/{pushId}/paymentDetails/balanceAmount' so the update is not called again.

Comment: When I update balance amount, path is `'payments/{pushId}/paymentDetails/balanceAmount'` or `'payments/{pushId}/balanceAmount'`? I hope the 2nd one right?

Comment: Awesome.. Yes I'll work on this.. Thank you so much once again for the help.. :)

Comment: One last doubt - `return paymentRef.child('balanceAmount').transaction(` will set the value to `balanceAmount` or what apporach should I be using here?

Comment: Yes see the documentation of transaction